# Printing the time in milliseconds in c++

Tags: c++, logging, sensors

HI I'm trying to log a sensor data to CSV file. I want the first row to be hh:mm:ss:ms.

The Code I have is

```
    #include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
eyeDataLog << std::ctime(&today_time) << ","
<< gazeleft[0] << ","
<< gazeleft[1] << ","
```

### |Timestamp2                 |left gaze X    |left gaze Y     |left gaze Z     |right gaze X

|Tue Mar  1 18:19:31 2022   |0             |0                |0               |0

how to add milliseconds to the logged time
regared thanks

Comment: [std::ctime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) don't have milliseconds. Maybe you should try something like [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [strftime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) or other library like [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which is included in c++20.

Update: even you don't use C++20, fmt library itself is compatible with c++11 and above.

Since you have formatting requirement in logging, fmt might fit well.

[Demo for fmt](https://godbolt.org/z/EKb59q9KG)

```
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
  using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
  fmt::print("Default format: {} {}\n", 42s, 100ms);
  // %S prints milliseconds
  fmt::print("strftime-like format: {:%H:%M:%S}\n", 3h + 15min + 30s + 15ms);
}
```